# 選択された曜日によって表示する時間を変更したいです。

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

現在レストランのサイトを制作しています。コンタクトフォームでユーザーが予約したい日付と時間帯を選択できるように"jquery UIのdatetimepicker"を使用しています。

#### 実現したいこと

選択された曜日によって表示する時間を変更したいです。
コードにも書いてありますが、
例）月、水、木、金曜日を選択 => 予約可能な時間は、'17:30', "17:45", '20:15', "20:30", "20:45" を表示
土、日曜日を選択 => 予約可能な時間は、'11:30', '11:45', '12:00', '12:15', '17:30', "17:45", '20:15', "20:30", "20:45" を表示

```js
let changeTimeRange = function(currentDateTime) {

    // 土、日曜日が選択されたら営業時間はallowTimesの範囲
    if (currentDateTime.getDay() == 6 && currentDateTime.getDay() == 0) {
        alert('weekends')
        this.setOptions({
            allowTimes: [
                '11:30', '11:45', '12:00', '12:15', '17:30', "17:45", '20:15', "20:30", "20:45"
            ],
        });

        // 月、水、木、金曜日が選択されたら営業時間はallowTimesの範囲
    } else if (currentDateTime.getDay() == 1 && currentDateTime.getDay() == 3 && currentDateTime.getDay() == 4 && currentDateTime.getDay() == 5)
        this.setOptions({
            allowTimes: [
                '17:30', "17:45", '20:15', "20:30", "20:45"
            ],
        });
};

jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('de');
$('.timepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: 1,
    timepicker: true,
    datepicker: true,
    // allowTimes: [
    //     '11:30', '11:45', '12:00', '12:15', '17:30', "17:45", '20:15', "20:30", "20:45"
    // ],
    allowTimes: changeTimeRange,
    format: 'd, F. Y, H:i',
    onChangeDateTime: changeTimeRange,
    onShow: changeTimeRange
});
```

参考サイト:
[datetimepickerドキュメント](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#ongenerate)

参考部分は

> ```
> (Set options runtime DateTimePicker #
> If select day is Saturday, the minimum set 11:00, otherwise 8:00)
> ```

指摘やアドバイス、参考になる記事をご存知の方がいればとても助かります。よろしくお願いします。

急ぎの案件なので [teratailにも同内容を投稿しました](https://teratail.com/questions/364225).

---

#### 追記（解決しました）

teratailで解決したので、こちらにも解決したコードを載せます。

```js
let changeTimeRange = function(currentDateTime) {
    if (currentDateTime.getDay() == 6 || currentDateTime.getDay() == 0) {
        this.setOptions({
            allowTimes: [
                '11:30', '11:45', '12:00', '12:15', '17:30', "17:45", '20:15', "20:30", "20:45"
            ],
        });
    } else if (currentDateTime.getDay() == 1 || currentDateTime.getDay() == 3 || currentDateTime.getDay() == 4 || currentDateTime.getDay() == 5)
        this.setOptions({
            allowTimes: [
                '17:30', "17:45", '20:15', "20:30", "20:45"
            ],
        });
};

jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('de');
$('.timepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: 1,
    timepicker: true,
    datepicker: true,
    format: 'd, F. Y, H:i',
    onChangeDateTime: changeTimeRange,
    onShow: changeTimeRange,
});
```

Comment: 解決した場合には質問に追記してしまうのではなく、**個別の回答** として投稿してみてください。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます！次回からそうします！